# Php file_get_content not working to fetch local image

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to convert image to string to encode_Base64 using file_get_contents() but it show file not found

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","table");

$hotel = $_GET['hotel'].'menu';


$query="SELECT * FROM $hotel";

if(($result = $conn->query($query))==TRUE){
    $product = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data= base64_encode(file_get_contents("Images\\".$row['image'].".jpg"));
        echo $data;
        $item = array(
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "name" => $row['Name'],
            "price" => $row['Price'],
            "description"  => $row['Description'],
            "img" => $data);
        array_push($product , $item);
        break;
    }
    echo "Images\\".$row['image'].".jpg";
    echo "<image src='Images\\".$row['image'].".jpg'>";
    //echo json_encode($product);
}

?>
```

But in last line when i echo same path it displays image

so what should i do

Comment: As far as I know, you cant use **prepared statements** for table name. the better option is having whitelist and wrapping your table name in ```

Answer (score -1):

You have missed part of the code.
It'll return what you want

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","table");

$hotel = $_GET['hotel'].'menu';


$query = "SELECT * FROM `$hotel`";

if (($result = $conn->query($query)) == TRUE) {
    $product = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //changed
        $path = "Images\\" . $row['image'] . ".jpg";
        $data = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));

        echo $data;
        $item = array(
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "name" => $row['Name'],
            "price" => $row['Price'],
            "description" => $row['Description'],
            "img" => $data);
        array_push($product, $item);
        break;
    }
    echo "Images\\" . $row['image'] . ".jpg";
    //echo "<image src='Images\\".$row['image'].".jpg'>";
    echo '<image src="' . $data . '">';
    echo '<image src="' . $path . '">';
    //echo json_encode($product);
}
```